# How to add a Timestamp to the end of a preselected row

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm working in VB and I've hit a seemingly simple issue...
I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a timestamp.

So The current code takes the row from the current worksheet we'll say from the Working(a) worksheet.  then it grabs anyting from the A Column and that says Completed.  Once it's found an instance of 'Completed' it then grabs the entire row (barring null) and places it into the Completed(d) worksheet at the most recent blank slot...

What i want to do...is once it places it in the Completed Worksheet I want to also add another cell to the end of the row it just pasted and add a timestamp for that day only. Meaning I don't want this date to change if it's opened on another day.

Any thoughts?

```
Dim z As Long
Dim a As Worksheet, b As Worksheet, c As Worksheet, d As Worksheet

Set a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Working")
Set b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Peer Review")
Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Waiting to Push")
Set d = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed")
z = 2

For z = a.Cells(a.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If a.Cells(z, "A").Value2 <> vbNullString Then
        Select Case UCase(a.Cells(z, "A").Value2)
            Case "WORKING"

            Case "PEER"
                b.Rows(b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = a.Rows(z).Value2
                a.Rows(z).Delete
            Case "WAITING"
                c.Rows(c.Cells(c.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = a.Rows(z).Value2
                a.Rows(z).Delete
            Case "COMPLETED"
                d.Rows(d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = a.Rows(z).Value2
                a.Rows(z).Delete
            Case Else

        End Select
    End If
Next z
For z = b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If b.Cells(z, "A").Value2 <> vbNullString Then
        Select Case UCase(b.Cells(z, "A").Value2)
            Case "WORKING"

            Case "PEER"

            Case "WAITING"
                c.Rows(c.Cells(c.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = b.Rows(z).Value2
                b.Rows(z).Delete
            Case "COMPLETED"
                d.Rows(d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = b.Rows(z).Value2
                b.Rows(z).Delete
            Case Else

        End Select
    End If
Next z
For z = c.Cells(c.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If c.Cells(z, "A").Value2 <> vbNullString Then
        Select Case UCase(c.Cells(z, "A").Value2)
            Case "WORKING"

            Case "PEER"
                b.Rows(b.Cells(b.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = c.Rows(z).Value2
                c.Rows(z).Delete
            Case "WAITING"

            Case "COMPLETED"
                d.Rows(d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value2 = c.Rows(z).Value2
                c.Rows(z).Delete
            Case Else

        End Select
    End If
Next z

End Sub
```

Comment: vba Is Not vb.net and that is not VB.NET code.  The words on the tags tell you when each is appropriate

Comment: `d.Cells(row, column).Value = Now`

Comment: ok....well when i added `d.Cells(z, "K").Value = Now` it still doesn't populate a timestamp...

Comment: Did it do **anything**?  What was the value of `z`?  I'm worried that you might have written it to row `z` without setting `z` to `d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` (after having updated column A with the new value) and therefore you have written the timestamp to the row in the destination sheet which was equivalent to the row in the **source** sheets.

Comment: that seems to be the case...so how would i go about setting z to `d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`?

Comment: cause when i change the z to 1 ti appears in the correct location

Comment: If you want the timestamp to go in row 1, then just say `d.Cells(1, "K").Value = Now` (or `d.Range("K1").Value = Now`).  If you want to set `z` to `d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` just say `z = d.Cells(d.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: perfect.  Thank you